# matplotlib creating a scatter plot via PathCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to dig deeper into matplotlib and learn how it works under the cover. So I thought it'd be a simple task to draw a few points on the canvas and connect them with some lines. I was wrong. I looked at the [source code for Axes.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/axes/_axes.html#Axes.scatter). So I wrote the following code:

```py
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes((0,0,1,1), frameon = True, xlim = (0,1), ylim = (0,1), xticks=[0.2], yticks=[0.2])
pos = [(0.2, 0.2), (0.2, 0.3), (0.3, 0.4), (0.4, 0.4), (0.5, 0.3), (0.5, 0.2), (0.35, 0.1)]
pp = Polygon([(0,0), (0.02, 0.02), (0.04, 0)])
#mypath = pp.get_path()
mypath = pp.get_path().transformed(pp.get_transform()) #*
dots = collections.PathCollection(paths = (mypath,), offsets= pos)
#dots.set_transform(transforms.IdentityTransform()).    #**
ax.add_collection(dots)
plt.show()
```

I expected that this would render 5 triangles in my canvas. But this only drew 1 triangle at the bottom left corner of the canvas. Substituting the line marked with * with the line above it doesn't change anything. Adding line marked with ** causes the single triangle to vanish too.
Can anyone tell me how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Could you explain what it is you really want to achieve? The matplotlib source contains a lot of internal code, with functions that often miss sufficient documentation to fully understand. These functions need to work with a huge combination of options, some already very old.  If you just want a scatter plot with triangles, there are many [markers](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html) to choose from. E.g. `ax.scatter(x, y, marker='^')`.

Comment: Before diving into the deep inner workings of matplotlib, it's recommended to study its general principles, such as [transforms](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) and [other tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/index.html).

Comment: @JohanC I know I can do it for scatter.  I want to learn the underlying structure of matplotlib in order to be able to contribute to the open source project in future. So this is mostly educational. I do not want to use any of the helper functions. I was planning on doing this and then going through artist code and seeing if I can create one by myself. 
 I've already gone through the tutorials that seemed relevant.   I think I can just create the triangles individually and give each of them a transform.  But I wanted to use a collection since it seems that's what the helper functions use.